# What does a GraphicsConfiguration represent in Java?

Tags: java

The Java 8 documentation describes GraphicsConfiguration in the following manner.

> The GraphicsConfiguration class describes the characteristics of a graphics destination such as a printer or monitor

The description is a bit non-technical and vague, though, it has been enough to allow me to use it in a screenshot application, but I still do not understand why a GraphicsDevice has multiple GraphicsConfigurations. In the documentation for GraphicsDevice it states:

> Each graphics device has one or more GraphicsConfiguration objects associated with it. These objects specify the different configurations in which the GraphicsDevice can be used.

What are these "different configurations" and when would they occur?

Comment: Pretty sure that means different resolutions/color depths/etc. supported by the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the Javadoc for this class:

> There can be many GraphicsConfiguration objects associated with a
>   single graphics device, representing different drawing modes or
>   capabilities. The corresponding native structure will vary from
>   platform to platform. For example, on X11 windowing systems, each
>   visual is a different GraphicsConfiguration. On Microsoft Windows,
>   GraphicsConfigurations represent PixelFormats available in the current
>   resolution and color depth.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsConfiguration.html

For X11 and the term "visual" this link clarifies a bit: http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/visual.html - Of course, for "normal" applications this might be irritating but since Java AWT uses the underlying OS graphics, it has to represent its characteristics.

Comment: This is the exact vagueness that I was talking about that I would have liked to be clarified. Terms like "each visual" and "represent different drawing modes or capabilities."

Comment: Well, maybe if you know a bit more about how X11 works, the term "visual" would make sense. Maybe this helps http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/visual.html - For "normal" applications this might be irritating but since Java awt uses the underlying OS graphic it has to represent its characteristics.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I guess I just have to read more into what these configurations mean. I was just not very sure what color configurations, color modes, etc, meant, and how a monitor could have multiples of them. If you could add you commented information to the answer then I will accept it.